# Loading image for different screen size with media query

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load image for different screen size with only media query but it doesn't display in the div container; when i check the browser it loads but isn't displaying. i don't know what i'm doing wrong

here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<pre>
    <script src="Jarts.js"></script>

</pre>
<div id="skjd2344jd"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

here's css

```
 #skjd2344jd{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px){
#skjd2344jd {
   background-image: url("../img/optimal_small.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
#skjd2344jd {
   background-image: url("../img/optimal.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `html, body {height: 100%;}` otherwise, your div will not show up when it has percentage height of `auto`... Also, you might need to add the HTML viewport meta tag in `head`

Comment: Sorry Its an oversight,  I've added all that before still doesn't display

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/7fpb1s0m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your id will take 100% width and height of your body but you didn't set dimention to your body so just add height to your body and dont forget `background-size:cover` so your code will look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6e4L47d7/)